# Для чего написано w++?

Tags: java, инкремент

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] mass; 
    int n, w;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите число элементов массива: ");
    n = in.nextInt();
    mass = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mass[i] = r.nextInt(101) - 50;
    char ch;
    w = 0;
    while (w < n) {
        if (w % 10 == 0) ch = '\n';
        else ch = ' ';
        System.out.format("%c[%3d]", ch, mass[w]);
        w++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Судя по тому, какую вы выбрали метку, вы уже знаете ответ.

Comment: ну без инкремента цикл то будет вечно а написано внутри а не в условии (while w++ < n) чтоб значение w было на 1 меньше когда прекращается цикл, потому что (while w++ < n) сделдает инкремент также когда условие неверно

Answer (score 1):

Проанализировав код пришёл к выводу:

```
w = 0;
    while (w < n) {
        if (w % 10 == 0) ch = '\n';
        else ch = ' ';
        System.out.format("%c[%3d]", ch, mass[w]);
        w++;
    }
}
```

Цикл выводит построчно по 9 элементов. Вместо вывода 10-го происходит перенос курсора на следующую строку.
В данном случае операция с переменной `w++` нужна для того, чтобы перебрать весь массив.

Я перепишу этот цикл с предусловием на цикл с параметром. Надеюсь, Вам станет понятнее.

```
for (w = 0; w < n; w++){
    if (w % 10 == 0) ch = '\n';
    else ch = ' ';
    System.out.format("%c[%3d]", ch, mass[w]);
}
```

И применю тернарный оператор:

```
for (w = 0; w < n; w++){
    ch = (w % 10 == 0)?'\n':' ';
    System.out.format("%c[%3d]", ch, mass[w]);
}
```